# Power Query - Group by MAX Column Value

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a transactional table that shows me multiple records per order.
[image]

Now I woule like to get per Order the Data, Value and Amount based on the MAX in Column Key.
Hiw is this possible by using Power Query?
The result would be like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a partition (group) per `Order`, sort the partition by `Key` descending, keep the first row, then combine those rows:

```
let
    Partitions = Table.Group(MyTable, {"Order"}, {{"Data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Key", Order.Descending}}),1), type table}}),
    Combined = Table.Combine(Partitions[Data])
in
    Combined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CT = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source, 
    {
      {"Order", Int64.Type}, 
      {"Date", type date}, 
      {"Value", Int64.Type}, 
      {"Amount", Int64.Type}, 
      {"Key", type number}
    }
  ), 
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(
    CT, 
    each ([Key] = List.Max(Table.SelectRows(CT, (q) => q[Order] = [Order])[Key]))
  )
```